# Regex, catching multiple tags

Tags: ruby, regex

so I have this for example:

```
<message>
test
test 
test
</message>
<message>
test2
test2
test2
</message>
```

And now I want to catch both things between `<message> and </message>`

I have this regex: `/<message>\n(.*)<\/message>\n/mi`
The result I get is this:

Match 1:

```
test
test 
test
</message>
<message>
test2
test2
test2
```

I want this to be the result:

Match 1:

```
test
test
test
```

Match 2:

```
test2
test2
test2
```

Is there a way to solve my problem? Thanks for every answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add a quantifier `?` inorder to do a reluctant match(*aka shortest possible match*).

```
<message>\n(.*?)<\/message>
```

[DEMO](http://www.rubular.com/r/IG4rID5aUW)

Comment: or `<message>\n(.*?)<\/message>(?=\n|$)`

Answer (score 1):

```
<[^>]*>(.*?)<\/[^>]*>
```

You can use this with g and s flags.See demo.

http://regex101.com/r/nG1gU7/33